# TFS work item type for requirements management targeting multiple platforms

Tags: tfs, requirements, tfs-workitem

In my company we are using TFS for projects targeting multiple platforms (Web, iOS, Android), and since we work on sensitive/regulated projects we have a lot of requirements to produce for each little detail of our softwares/algorithms.

The problems comes when we have requirements that are shared on multiple platforms (a common algorithm for example) and for that we found 2 solutions: either we duplicate the requirements for each platform, or we create additional columns on the requirement itself (like the state column which is duplicated for each platform for example..).

With the first solution it becomes hard to maintain requirements (mostly when you have thousands of entries..) and with the 2nd solution we get a really ugly template, that needs to change when a new platform is targeted and traceability with tests cases is not that good...

So I was wondering if there is a "known/official" solution for theses cases. When I looked at the test case work item type, I noticed that there's the notion of "test point" that represents the test case for a given "test configuration", so maybe the solution is to create a new work item type that would represent the platform (and store the state on the given platform for example).

Anyway, I'm taking any advice/suggestion on that topic :)

Answer (score 0):

Tagging was specifically designed to solve just this sorry of issue. In TFS 2013 you can add tags to work items and query based on those tags. If you are running your Test Cases in multiple environments it is bad practice to have duplicate test cases. You should instead use the "Configuration" function that can be applied to each of your Test Cases, blanket, or specific. This allows you to have a single Test Cases that has been passed in iOS but not passed on Android or WP. You can even remove configurations for features that are specific only to a single PBI.

In TFS 2015 you will be able to have the tags display on the cards in the kanban views.

Comment: Sorry, but that does not solve the problem at all. Tagging a requirement with the platform doesn't give a new ID to it for each platform, so the traceability Test Case <-> Requirement, is still wrong. Moreover with your option I still need to duplicate the state columns for each platform for example.

Comment: From a regulatory perspective, the better way for us is to duplicate the requirements, so the iOS test case is linked with the iOS requirement, the Web test case is linked to the web requirements and so on.. This is just stupid that we cannot get something similar to the test points for requirements.

Comment: Why can you not have the iOS test case linked to a common requirement?  That common requirement may have multiple test cases for each platform.
Think of it this way.  If your requirement is "Display User Data on profile page", you could have a test case for "Validate iOS devices show UserData on profile page", "Validate Android Devices show Userdata on Profile Page", etc etc.

Comment: having a common requirement means duplicating some fields (like status) in the requirement work item type for each platform. And more problematic, there's no easy way to check that a requirement is associated with a test case for each platform.

Comment: Why do you have different requirements? Don't you have a Feature that is common and then PBI for each platform to maintain tractability?